# how should i remove + from my string url (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, api, urlencode, url-encoding

Question :: how to remove + from my string url

Problem :: while calling api i am getting + symbol at the end of url so how can i remove that +

here is my code which removing space

```
extension String {
  func encodeURL() -> String {
    return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of ANY occurrences of '+' you could use this

```
let cleanString =  self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "")
```